# Angular: Script reference does not work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm coding a little Angular app for school and I have the problem that my script cannot be imported (It writes '{{1+1}}'). 
The index.html and app.js files are in the same folder. 
[Picture: Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbW6W.png)

But if I code the script directly into the index.html it works 
[Here it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5AMt.png)

I just started learning JavaScript, so please forgive me if the question is dumb :)

Thanks
Bene

Comment: The script tag in your screenshot has **scr** instead of **src**.Change it to `<script src="app.js"></script>` instead of `<script scr="app.js"></script>`

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem

Comment: @bene.austria Do you see any network errors in the console? 404 messages or anything like that?

Answer (score 0):

Simple typing mistake. It should look like this

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

But in the future, please post code in the original post, not in a picture.

Plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/lQuKmlthSxT0pIKIIrtl?p=preview

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem.
The html is provided by a node js webserver, is this relevant?

Comment: Yes it does. I just created a plunker. The problem was you entered `scr` instead of `src`

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea why it doesn't work for me: http://i.imgur.com/qqDe9ZB.png

Comment: in the browser console, it don't even find the app.js: http://i.imgur.com/bllhnWy.png

Answer (score 0):

Try using other version of angular, like:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

It seems like you dont put "http:" after the url

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got the solution!

My index.html is provided by a NodeJS-Webserver. So the webserver only loaded the html file. So I wrote: app.use(... app.js ...) and it worked.